# Using Symfony Doctrine Migrations with Gitlab CI: GitLab CI interprets "Nothing to migrate" as error

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, gitlab-ci

We are using the Doctrine migrations bundle for update database in our deployment process. Currently, we are switching to Gitlab-CI.

The problem: The CI is aborting the deployment process because the output of command `php sf doctrine:migrations:diff` contains stderr.

The part of our .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
deploy_live:
  type: deploy
  environment:
    name: live
    url: 1.2.3.4
  script:
      - ssh root@1.2.3.4 "cd /var/www/html/ && git pull origin master && exit"
      - ssh root@11.2.3.4 "cd /var/www/html/ && composer install -n && exit"
      - ssh root@1.2.3.4 "cd /var/www/html/ && php sf doctrine:migrations:diff --env=prod && exit"
      - ssh root@1.2.3.4 "cd /var/www/html/ && php sf doctrine:migrations:migrate -n --env=prod && exit"
      - 'ssh root@1.2.3.4 "cd /var/www/html/ && chown www-data:www-data . -R && exit"'
  only:
    - master
```

Output of Gitlab CI:

```
$ ssh root@1.2.3.4 "cd /var/www/html/ && php sf doctrine:migrations:diff --env=prod && exit"
#!/usr/bin/env php

In NoChangesDetected.php line 13:

  No changes detected in your mapping information.  


doctrine:migrations:diff [--configuration [CONFIGURATION]] [--db-configuration [DB-CONFIGURATION]] [--editor-cmd [EDITOR-CMD]] [--filter-expression [FILTER-EXPRESSION]] [--formatted] [--line-length [LINE-LENGTH]] [--check-database-platform [CHECK-DATABASE-PLATFORM]] [--db DB] [--em [EM]] [--shard SHARD] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--] <command>

ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

This may be a bug, but maybe it can be circumvented?

FYI: `sf` is a symlink to `bin/console`.

Comment: Is redirecting stderr to stdout as a quick fix `console doctrine:migrations:diff 2>&1`  an option? You may want to clear doctrine's metadata cache before running the migrations, too. The command is `console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata`.

Comment: No, redirecting to stdout does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I just found a solution:

1. move the commands excecuted directly from the `gitlab-ci.yml` file unter `script` to an shell script `deploy.sh`
2. move this script via scp to the server

**gitlab-ci.yml**

```
deploy_live:
  type: deploy
  environment:
    name: live
    url: 1.2.3.4
  script:
      - scp deploy.sh root@1.2.3.4:/var/www/html/
      - ssh root@1.2.3.4 "cd /var/www/html/ && chmod +x deploy.sh && ./deploy.sh && exit"
  only:
    - master
```

**deploy.sh**

```
cd /var/www/html/
git add --all
git commit -m "changes"
git pull origin master

composer install -n
php sf doctrine:cache:clear-metadata --env=prod
php sf doctrine:migrations:diff --env=prod
php sf doctrine:migrations:migrate -n --env=prod

php sf cache:clear --env=prod

exit
```

Answer (score 0):

They added option for such case: `--allow-no-migration` - can you try it?

see: https://github.com/doctrine/migrations/blob/ebd2551c7767375fcbc762b48d7dee4c18ceae97/lib/Doctrine/Migrations/Tools/Console/Command/MigrateCommand.php#L64